# React Native Navigation Experimental Lifecycle Method Called on Pop Route?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using NavigationExperimental with React Native. Are any of the lifecycle methods invoked when a pop route happens?

For example:
Scene A => Scene B

If I pop the route on Scene B, I want Scene A to re-render.

Answer (score 0):

FirstPageComponent.js

```
 pressBtn() {
    let _this = this;
    const { navigator } = this.props;
    if (navigator) {
      navigator.push({
        name: 'SecondPageComponent',
        component: SecondPageComponent,
        title: 'page2',
        params: {
          name: 'glm',
          getFeedBack: function(text) {
            _this.setState({feedback: text});
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

SecondPageComponent.js:

```
  pressBtn() {
    const { navigator } = this.props;
    if (navigator) {
      this.props.getFeedBack('Im fine');
      navigator.pop();
    }
  }
```

call getFeedBack When you pop Second page, the getFeedBack will change the state of First page, then First page will be re-rendered.